# water coming out of bathroom faucet when I turn on my kitchen faucet

Tags: plumbing

When I turn on my kitchen faucet water starts coming out of my bathroom faucet. Not sure whats going. Would like to know incase of serious problem.

Comment: Who're you gonna call? *Ghostbusters!*

Answer (score 1):

that's weird.  Only thing that makes sense is that your faucet needs new washers or seals.  The water pressure could actually be making a tighter seal.  When you loose water pressure it leaks.  Some times its easier just to replace faucet.